# How can I select records from two different tables in one MySQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have first names stored in one table and last names stored in another. I know this is silly but I am trying out different things as I'm just starting with MySQL. Anyway is it possible to select the first name from one table and the last name from another in one query? And put the result inside a PHP variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must have something that binds the two tables together, that is a common `key`. Something like `Id` in the example below:

```
Table 1

Id Fname
--------
1 Roger
2 Pete

Table 2

Id Lname
--------
1 Federer
2 Sampras
```

In that case you can get the full name as:

```
SELECT Fname, Lname from T1,T2 where T1.Id = T2.Id;
```

Comment: +1 for answer. This is what is called a "foreign key" in database terminology. A key value that connects records across tables.

Comment: Explicit JOINs using the JOIN clause are generally preferred over implicit joins using the WHERE clause because you separate the join criteria from the filter criteria, which usually leads to more readable SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use [joins](http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_left_join.php)

```
SELECT firstName, lastName  
FROM Table1, Table2 
WHERE (Table1.id = Table2.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.firstname, table2.lastname from table1, table2
    where table1.id = table2.id
```

See [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30875&seqNum=5) for more information.

> **The Full Join**
>
> If a SELECT statement names multiple tables in the FROM clause with the names separated by commas, MySQL performs a full join.